# npm-debug.log is in .gitignore file, but I still get the messsage "nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)"

Tags: git, logging, npm-debug

My gitignore file looks like this:

```
*.csv
*.dat
*.iml
*.log
*.out
*.pid
*.seed
*.sublime-*
*.swo
*.swp
*.tgz
*.xml
.DS_Store
.idea
.project
.strong-pm
coverage
node_modules
npm-debug.log
server-info
definitions/
```

Yet, suddenly `git status` shows me a lot of npm-debug.log files in red.
[image]

I also get the message

> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to
>   track)

How do I remove all the npm-debug.log files from my local machine without accidentally deleting any important files?

Also, how do I prevent these files from being created in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `npm-debug.log*` to your `.gitignore` file, because the current status of the `.gitignore` file means `npm-debug.log` only.

Adding asterisk `*` will ensure that any file starting with `npm-debug.log` will be ignored

If you want to delete them forever from your machine use the following command:

```
rm -f npm-debug.log.*
```

Answer (score 2):

To ignore the npm-debug files on Git you're missing a star at the end of the string in your .gitignore file.

`npm-debug.log*`

And if you want to never generate those logs, you can execute the install with `--loglevel=silent`, anyway I don't recommend to do that, they may be useful.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I'm taking your advice and will NOT use --loglevel=silent.